# I'm creating a smart contract to interact with specific NFTs. Is there a function to filter a specific NFT contract address?

Tags: solidity, nft

I wanted to create a smart contract that only interacts with a specific NFT. I know there is a "tokenID" attribute I don't think this is unique. Cronoscan shows multiple collections that have the same tokenIDs. Does anyone know if smart contracts can filter based on a contract address? I'd like to accomplish this with as little gas as possible.

Sorry if this is a basic question but I've Googled and searched this message board for the answer but was not able to find on other that someone trying to sell their service.

I Google and search Stack Overflow but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each contract will have their own set of ids and therefore they are not unique between contracts only unique for each contract.

This checks if the code size for the address is > 0. This will have to be implemented on a new contract or you will have to find an existing contract with this functionality to view/execute it

```
function isContract(address addressValue) public view returns (bool) {
    uint size;
    assembly { size := extcodesize(addressValue) }
    return size > 0;
}
```

Also notice this is a view function and for that reason wont cost any gas to execute.

In regards to someone selling it as a service, you can get it yourself by just deploying this contract on whatever main net you want (by the sounds of it Cronos).

```
'// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

 pragma solidity 0.8.7;

 contract ContractIdentifier{

      function isContract(address addressValue) public view returns (bool) {
          uint size;
          assembly { size := extcodesize(addressValue) }
          return size > 0;
      }
 }
```